# Is saving user's id and login token in local storage a good idea?

Tags: django, reactjs, authentication, redux, django-rest-framework

I am developing `Django + React` project and I'm caught with this security approach concerning login and managing views for the logged in user.

I am using `django-rest-framework` or **DRF** for my `RESTful API`. And I'm using `django-rest-knox` for authenticating user logins since I am implementing Token-based authentication *(instead of session-based which uses `CSRF`)*.

**Question: Is it a good idea to save user's id and token in local storage?**

Currently, I have a `/auth/login/` API endpoint that handles the backend logic of logging in user and returns JSON response of login details upon successful login (including user `id` and `token`).

In my frontend, I use `redux` and `redux-persist` so the user's login details are kept even when the site is refreshed. The way `redux-persist` do it is that it saves the response in `local storage`. This means that the user `id` and `token` can be accessed and changed anytime thru `dev tools`.

If user will then make a `POST` request to an API that requires a `Token authentication header`, the frontend will look into that local storage for the `token` value to be supplied to the request header.

If user will then make a `POST` request to an API where the user `id` is required in the request data, the frontend will also look for the id in the local storage.

Comment: Cookies with SameSite, HttpOnly and Secure flags are far more secure, they are not accessible by any front-end scripts so are less vulnerable to any security flaws in your front-end app

Answer (score 0):

Localstorage [is not safe](https://snyk.io/blog/is-localstorage-safe-to-use/), especially for storing tokens and ids. Any user can go to the browser's developer tools, see and also edit its contents, for example.

You could check on [Django's sessions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/sessions/), so you can store data securely at server side and keep its contents associated with a specific user. There is a great [tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Django/Sessions) at Mozilla that explains sessions in a clearer way than the official documentation.